# Mysql Query is so slow

Tags: php, mysql

So I have Mysql like this

```
SELECT `A`.`ID`, 
IFNULL((SELECT * FROM `B` WHERE `B`.`To` = `A`.`ID`),0)
FROM `A` 
ORDER BY (LOG10(IF(ABS(`X`)>=1,ABS(`X`),1))+(SIGN(`X`)*((`A`.`Date`)-1410530785))/45000) DESC
```

The B table has about 20k rows.

Why is it so slow, It takes more than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite an `ORDER BY` clause. Storing that value fixed in an additional, indexed, row will probably solve your problem.

What you are doing now, is calculating that value for every row every time you run that query. And that takes time.